# How to set the value of a Spring application property dynamically in test cases?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

Let's assume that in a Spring Boot application, I have a test `application.yaml` file under `src/test/resources` that contains the following property definition:

```
some:
  property: ${some.property}
```

Also let's suppose that my test class looks like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PortServiceTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static MyClassRule classRule = new MyClassRule()

    @Autowired
    private MyDependency dependency;

    @Test
    public void shouldPopulateEnvironmentWithWiremockPort() {
        // test body
    }

}
```

where `MyClassRule` has a method named `ruleValue()` that makes some calculations and returns a given value:

```java
public class MyClassRule {
    public int ruleValue() {
         // some calculations
         return value;
    }
}
```

I want to set the value of `${some.property}` to the return value of `MyClassRule.ruleValue()` before the dependencies are injected to the test and the tests start -- probably even before the Spring context is initialized.

I thought I can use a custom test execution listener:

```java
public class CustomTestExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        Class<?> testClass = testContext.getTestClass();
        Field[] fields = testClass.getFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getType() == MyClassRule.class) {
                ClassRule annotation = field.getAnnotation(ClassRule.class);
                if (annotation == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                MyClassRule myClassRule = (MyClassRule) field.get(testClass);
                int ruleValue = myClassRule.ruleValue();
                ApplicationContext context = testContext.getApplicationContext();
                Environment environment = context.getEnvironment();

                // how to set {some.value} in environment?

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but:

1. By the time the code in the test execution listener is executed, the context is already initialized and the test will have no chance to even execute as `${some.property}` cannot be resolved
2. I am not sure how can I inject `${some.property}` into the environment.

So how can I set the value of `${some.property}` to the return value of `MyClassRule.ruleValue()` in an elegant, transparent, and reusable way?

Answer (score 2):

Spring ReflectionTestUtils is a collection of reflection-based utility methods for use in unit and integration testing scenarios.

Using ReflectionTestUtils.setField, you should be able to set field (where you injecting value) with value on the "targetClass".

```
@Before
public void setup(){
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classRule , "fieldName", value);
}
```

Comment: Try to move `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` in the static block inside test class. Otherwise think about possibilities to change the source code, because if you cannot to test that code - that means you have some problems, better to rewrite or change architecture of code.